# Xcode moving from view to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm coding in Xcode, and i have a problem moving from view to view (xib to xib) My xib-files all have a personal .h and .m file.

this is the code i have:

The code to go from the first view to the quiz view in this case:

```
-(IBAction)switchviewMainToQuiz:(id)sender {

    ViewControllerQuiz *quizView = [[ViewControllerQuiz alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:quizView animated:YES];

}
```

The code to go back from a view to my first view:

```
-(IBAction)switchviewQuizToMain:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

the problem is that the second code just goes back and that gives sometimes an error or a fail in the app. So when i go to other views and then want to go back it often gets stuck. So does someone have an other code to switch the views, or maybe an other solution? Thank You!

Comment: ok but what kind of error? anyway presentModalViewController is deprecated you should use instead [presentViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create new viewController in IBAction. For me i would do this in this way:

1 Create property with viewController:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *quizView ;
```

2 Synthesize it:

```
@synthesize quizView = _quizView;
```

3 Create method:

```
- (UIViewController *) quizView {
    if (_quizView == nil) {
        _quizView = [[ViewControllerQuiz alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    }
    return _quizView;
}
```

4 In your IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)switchviewMainToQuiz:(id)sender {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.quizView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you like my answer please vote it up to make it helpful for other users.